# Automatically turn ON usb debugging mode of Android device using java

Tags: java, android, usb

Is there any technique in java through which we can get into android device and turn on its USB debugging mode ON.

Answer (score 2):

I hope not. It is obiviously an inherent security risk to enable and should thus only be enabled if you are really sure what you are doing (e.g. if you are a developer testing an app).

Comment: But we can turn it ON through device's developer option. So, there must be some thing in java which will help us in doing similar thing through code.

Answer (score 2):

This is only available for system apps in respect of security. If your device is rooted you are able to call this:

```
Settings.Secure.putInt(getActivity().getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ADB_ENABLED, 1);
```

Comment: Ok. But what if the device is not rooted. Is there any way to do this? Like after connecting device with pc the device should prompt a message saying turn on usb debugging mode on.

Comment: As he said, only system apps can do this. For instance HTC Sense has own system apps for that.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Which means through Java we cannot do this.